# Javascript Array formatting

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am new to javascript, recently I am studying javascript array and object.

if I have a object

```
const initialValue = {
  a: 30,
  b: 40,
  c: 50
}

const initialValueKey = Object.keys(initialValue)

const [, , , ...value] = initialValueKey;
```

I wonder what is this `[, , , ...value]` expression, I know ...is spread operator, but i'm not sure what the value of `[, , , ...value]` here.

Comment: It's skipping the first 3 values and assigning the rest of the array to `value`. Try making your `initialValue` with more properties to see the difference

Comment: it's a complicated way to write `const value = initialValueKey.slice(3);`

Answer (score 3):

It is a way to retrieve "other values", or retrieving the values and skipping the first `n`.

Here's an example:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5
};

const data = Object.keys(obj);

const [,,, ...values] = data;

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to assign the variables to arrays. the two commas in this example skipsthe first 2 elements

```js
const initialValue = {
  a: 30,
  b: 40,
  c: 50,
  d: 70
}

const initialValueKey = Object.keys(initialValue)

const [, , ...value] = initialValueKey;

console.log(value);
```